# What is wrong in the below findstr example

Tags: batch-file

The following FINDSTR example gives me error.

```
"%JAVA%" -version 2>&1 | findstr /I hotspot > nul
```

***Error***: 'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, you need to make sure that `findstr.exe` actually exists (in `c:\windows\system32` by default).

If not (unlikely), that's your problem.

If it does exist, make sure that the directory it exists in is in your path. Executing `path` from a command window will show this.

Try to execute:

```
echo hello | findstr /I hello
```

and see what happens. If that works and the Java one doesn't, it's possible that Java itself may be modifying the path in a way that makes `findstr` disappear.

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean "find". Try,

```
find /?
```

Comment: No, findstr is the Windows equivalent of grep.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click On My Computer - Advanced - Environment Variables - System Variables - Select Path variable - append the below

C:\WINDOWS\system32